# Bokeh Heatmap error: object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: bokeh

Firstly the Bokeh Heatmap google search result is broken. Secondly when I try the Google cache version of the Heatmap code, or for that matter any other examples of the Heatmap code I can find, I keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Am trying to run this in Jupyter and i suspect it's failing on splitting the input data but not sure how to correct.

Is the code wrong, or is it my system that is somehow wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import HeatMap, output_file, show

z = pd.DataFrame()
z['date'] = ['2016-01-15', '2016-01-13', '2016-01-11', '2016-01-14', '2016-01-15']
z['hour'] = [12, 10, 11, 3, 0]
z['i'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

output_file('/tmp/test.html')
hm = HeatMap(z, x='date', y='hour', stat='count')
show(hm)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas very recently introduced a breaking change into a new version. For the moment, to continue using `bokeh.charts` your best bet is to downgrade your Pandas version.

Comment: I'd also direct you to some of the information about `bkcharts` here: https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2017/6/13/release-0-12-6/ and encourage you to take a look at Holoviews. The upcoming HV release will already be better than `bkcharts` in many ways and has a full team supporting it going forward. We will be encouraging every to look at HV as a great very-high level interface on top of Bokeh going forward.

Comment: Do we know if bokeh.charts have sorted the issue for this ? OR is Pandas downgrade still the best option ?